# Android Notification Max Priority doesn't work

Tags: android, delphi, notifications, delphi-10.1-berlin

I'm using this code to present a notification on top of the screen (like WhatsApp) but doesn't work at any cost, it only shows the icon on the notification bar.

```
TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    begin
       TThread.Synchronize(TThread.CurrentThread,procedure()
       var
       pru:integer;
        begin
        pru := 2;
if NotifAudio then begin
MediaPlayer1.FileName := (TPath.GetDocumentsPath + PathDelim + 'iclassy.mp3');
MediaPlayer1.Play;
end;
  BIIntent:= TAndroidHelper.Context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(TAndroidHelper.Context.getPackageName());
  BresultPendingIntent:=  TJPendingIntent.JavaClass.getActivity(TAndroidHelper.Context, 0, BIIntent, TJPendingIntent.JavaClass.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
  BntfBuilder:= TJNotificationCompat_Builder.JavaClass.init(TAndroidHelper.Context);
  BntfBuilder.setSmallIcon(TAndroidHelper.Context.getResources.getIdentifier(StringToJString('ic_bad_area'), StringToJString('drawable'), TAndroidHelper.Context.getPackageName));
  BntfBuilder.setContentTitle(StrToJCharSequence('Title'));
  BntfBuilder.setContentText(StrToJCharSequence('Subtext'));
  BntfBuilder.setPriority(pru);
  BntfBuilder.setContentIntent(BresultPendingIntent);
  BntfBuilder.setAutoCancel(False);
  if FixNotif2 = True then BntfBuilder.setOngoing(True);
  BntfBuilder.setPriority(pru); // priority is set to MAX (2)
  BNtf:= BntfBuilder.build;
  BadArea_Bool := True;
  ntfManager:= TJNotificationManager.Wrap((TAndroidHelper.Context.getSystemService(TJContext.JavaClass.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as ILocalObject).GetObjectID);
  ntfManager.cancel(1);
  ntfManager.notify(2, BNtf);
end);
end).Start();
```

Yet, the WhatsApp notification on top is showed normally, I also tried different phones but nothing, the notification doesn't show the rounded rectangle on top of the screen, just add the small icon on the notification bar. Am I missing something?

Comment: Cant you simply use the TNotification Center compoent?

Comment: TNotification Center doesn't support: Ongoing notification, set icon different from application, set Intent when clicking the notification, notification Priorities and hell knows why it crashes my Android application when typing.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by including to vibrate:

```
BntfBuilder.setDefaults(pru); // pru = 2
```